# Performing build using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere, git-svn

I have my java based custom application. I am very much new to `Jenkins` and I have a requirement where Jenkins should perform build activities on check in/commit files in SVN for my application.

What are the steps or processes that needs to be followed for working with Jenkins and SVN while working on a custom java based application.

Please guide.

Comment: why not using  git and gitlab? Have a try,It's more excellent.

Answer (score 4):

You can have Jenkins poll for changes and build when one or more commits have been detected. By decreasing the wait time between polling you can trigger a build on a new commit.

You can set this in the following location:

- Go to your project > Configure
- Scroll down to 'Build Triggers'
- select 'Poll SCM'

Here you can set your polling schedule to:
H/5 * * * *

this setting makes Jenkins poll your configured source repository every 5 minutes. The '?'-button behind the input field explains more detailed use.

***edit***: for setting up Jenkins in general I recommend the same [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html) by vogella mentioned by henriquedsg89, or [this tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/04/19/continuous-integration-server-for-django-using-jenkins/) which also gives more information about other possibly interesting settings for use with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

At jenkins click at **New Job**, type the project name and chose a initial configuration, can be **free-style**. At configuration page, select the **source code management** as **Subversion** and type the svn configs. 
There you can add **Build steps**, where you can chose to execute a shell script or whatever and move up or down the build step.

Here is a good article about configuring jenkins to an android app.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements there are 3 high tier steps but Jenkins has pretty helpful tooltips for each of these:

1. Configure your source code repository. This can be done globally or per job. (Ie; git etc). Do this as one job and test before moving on.
2. Configure how you would like Jenkins to be notified of new builds on your repo.(Poll SCM, or you can look at this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin))
3. Configure [Gradle within Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) to do your Java builds.

Low level tiers are whether your are hosting Jenkins locally or on a hosted environment which could affect how you need to setup your Jenkins environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a super late answer, never the less it might be useful for someone who checks it out later. There are mechanisms to do away with polling. There is a plugin which would trigger Jenkins on commit pushes to repo. It is available for Git and Subversion. However, do note that it is necessary to enable polling for this commit trigger to work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Click on New Job tag on the left upper corner:
It will bring up a webpage that you have to give a job name also choose a style.
You should choose either a free-style or Maven project if you are using maven to build your project.

As you said, you are using SVN. Then you should choose Subversion under the Source Code Management options. Copy our svn URL there and it might ask you to enter credentials. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qgvo.png)

You might have one generic account provided or your own.

Use the build tools to build the application. Depends on what unit test or other code metrics you want to test out, you might can utilize some plugins for your after build process. You can use JUnit to have a plot of your unit test in track. Also, you can choose the person you want to send the email to if the build failed.

Hope this is helpful.

Video reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR0LabeUQ88